# Test class code coverage for issue for standard API class

Tags: rest-api, api, code-coverage, callout

hello i am writing test class to get lead records using standard api,

Apex Class:

```java
@RestResource(urlMapping='/leadAPI/*')
global with sharing class CSP2_OppLeadSharing_to_SMIT_Callout {
    @HttpGet
    global static void getConvertedLead() {
        try{
            
            RestRequest leadrequest = RestContext.request;
            Map<String, String> leadRequestParams =leadrequest.params;
            //Integer leadlimit = Integer.valueOf(leadRequestParams.get('limit'));
            String RecordType =leadRequestParams.get('Record_type_name__c');
            String country =leadRequestParams.get('Country__c');
            String dealerId = leadRequestParams.get('Dealer_ID__c');
            list<lead> myLead = [SELECT Id,Salutation,Name from Lead
                                ];

           if(Name==null){
 RestContext.response.statusCode = 400;
                SalesforceError[] err = new SalesforceError[]{ 
                    new SalesforceError( '400','missing mandatory field ', 'unauthorized access' )
                        };
                            RestContext.response.responseBody = Blob.valueOf(JSON.serialize(err));
                RestContext.response.addHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
            }
        }
}
            else{
                RestContext.response.statusCode = 500;
                SalesforceError[] err = new SalesforceError[]{ 
                    new SalesforceError( '500','Internal Server Error ', 'Generic error.' )
                        };
                            RestContext.response.responseBody = Blob.valueOf(JSON.serialize(err));
                RestContext.response.addHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
            }
        }
        catch(exception e){
            
        }
    }
    //standard salesforce error response structure
    global class SalesforceError {
        public String errorCode;
        public String message;
        public String statusCode;
        public SalesforceError(String statusCode,String errorCode, string message){
            this.statusCode=statusCode;
            this.errorCode = errorCode;
            this.message = message;
        }
    }
}
```

test class:

```java
@isTest
public class CSP2_OppLeadSharing_to_SMIT_CalloutTest {
    
    public static testMethod void getLeadsTest(){
        Lead leads = new Lead();
        leads.firstname='test';
leads.salutation='Ms.';
        leads.LastName='test lastname';
        insert leads;
        //Test.startTest();
        RestRequest req = new RestRequest(); 
        RestResponse res = new RestResponse();
        req.requestURI = '/services/apexrest/leadapi;
        req.httpMethod = 'GET';
       req.addParameter('Name','test');
      
        
        req.addHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');        req.requestBody=Blob.valueof('{}');
        RestContext.request = req;
        RestContext.response= res;
        res.addHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        CSP2_OppLeadSharing_to_SMIT_Callout.getConvertedLead();
        Test.stopTest();
    
    }
}
```

the above test class covering only 1 error code "404" and getting code coverage 54%,
can you please help me how to cover reaming error codes, i have tried multiple codes but nothing is working

Answer (score 2):

#### The pillars of Testing

As a reminder...

- You only gain coverage for code that is executed as part of a test method
- You are responsible for creating, in your tests, *all* of the data that the code being tested requires to run (and to execute the specific code path you want to stress)
- Showing that your code behaves correctly (by making assertions) is the most important part of testing, not code coverage
- By testing a sufficient range of scenarios (in separate test methods), you will naturally gain high code coverage

#### The immediate issue

Looks to me like the main issue exists in your test data. There are some other issues (your test is asserting against the RestContext's response before your SUT is executed, only a single test method, not enough assertions, using the deprecated `testMethod` keyword instead of `@isTest`, etc...) but the test data is probably the thing holding you back the most right now.

The query for `myLeads` in your SUT (system under test) includes three filters:

- Record_type_name__c = :RecordType
- Country__c = :country
- Dealer_ID__c = :dealerId

The paramaters that you're setting for the RestContext's request specify "Opportunity Lead Record Type", "France", and "4765" respectively.

But when you're creating the `Lead` record for this test, you aren't setting the Dealer Id or the Country. Thus the query in your SUT returns no rows and you execute the code path that returns early with a 404.

In a test, you are responsible for setting up *all of the data that the code you're testing needs in order to execute*.

If Record_Type_Name__c is a formula field, then you'll need to set the RecordTypeId for your test Lead.
If Dealer_Id__c is a relationship field, then you'll need to create a Dealer__c record and insert it before you create your test Lead (so that you can populate the field with the Dealer__c's Id).
If they're just text fields, then you can set them without much fuss.

#### That alone won't get you the coverage you're looking for

Each branch in an if/else if/else is mutually exclusive. Sometimes, you could get away with having multiple records that each go through a different path. However, it's not a great idea to try to cover multiple if/else if/else branches in a single test. A failure in one would mean the entire test fails, and debugging things one at a time is slow. Using separate test methods for each branch is the way to go, as it makes it easier to see what is and what isn't working (and more quickly get the big-picture view of the code being tested).

In your situation though, you *must* have separate test methods to stress each branch after your query. You will only and always get a single result list from a query, so it's impossible to cover both the `if(!myLead.isEmpty())` and `else if(myLead.isEmpty())` branches in a single test method.

#### Parting advice

You should also be on the lookout for things that don't make sense or are impossible.

The `else if(myLead == null)`, for example, is impossible to enter. A query will *never* return a null result. The worst you'd get would be either an empty list, or an exception (if the running user doesn't have access to the object). Since it is impossible to enter, it should be removed entirely.

You should also decide on some code style guidelines, and use them consistently. Being consistent is the important part here. The general guidelines that I think most people have adopted are:

- Class names start with an Upper Case letter (so `MyClass` or `My_Class`)
- Variable names start with a lower case letter (so `myVariable` or `my_variable`)
- Use descriptive variable names (so instead of `a`, use `myAccount`)
- Single variables have singular names, collections have plural names (so `myAccount` is a single Account, and `accountsById` is a `Map<Id, Account>`)

Comment: Thank you @Derek F it resolved my issue, i have created separate test methods for each if else condition.

Comment: We are received one more requirement like to create callout class for 'PUT' method, I want to add LeadId__C field in url params ,  can you please help me how can I add this field in url as mandatory, can you please help me how to create class. I am new to standard API creation.